# How to expose context data to specific routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context, reach-router

I'm using react hooks with context API for sharing data between multiple components and using reach router for routing. My code looks something like this:

```
function App() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
   <ContextProvider>
    <Router>
      <Comp1 path='/comp1' >
        <Comp2 path="/"/>
      </Comp1>
      <Comp3 path="/comp3" />
    </Router>
   </ContextProvider>
 </div>
);
}
```

In this example, whatever data exposed by *ContextProvider* will be available to all the components. My question is, how can I expose the context only to Comp3 but not to Comp1 and Comp2?

Note: I'm using reach router.

Answer (score 0):

@Tien Duong, we had the same thought as yours. But it turns out the reach router internally works by mapping the component to the location configured to render them, it does not even take div

Funny how client side routing it taking shape, also they say they would be passing some route props to the Component mapped with the location.

It's like opening your house for anyone to enter. Where is the isolation in this case.